# How to insert enum data on Mysql from Php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have created an Enum on mylsql like this enum('male', 'female') but when I wanna insert data, I have some errors on just enum column. I shared my codes and error message. By the way I am using this class 
https://github.com/tommyknocker/pdo-database-class

```
This is error message.
    D:\wamp64\www\newchat\register_control.php:30:
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '01000' (length=5)
      1 => int 1265
      2 => string 'Data truncated for column 'gender' at row 1' (length=43)
    male
```

HTML

```
<div class="input-group form-group">
                        <label class="radio">Male
                          <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="gender" value="male" />
                          <span class="radiocheckmark"></span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio">Female
                          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />
                          <span class="radiocheckmark"></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
```

PHP

```
// Get data from FROM
    $name       =$_POST["name"];
    $surname    =$_POST["surname"];
    $email      =$_POST["email"];
    $username   =$_POST["username"];
    $password   =$_POST["password"];
    $password2  =$_POST["password2"];
    $gender     =$_POST["gender"];

    // Insert data in db
    $data = [
        'name' => 'name',
        'surname' => 'surname',
        'email' => 'email',
        'username' => 'username',
        'gender' => 'gender',
        'password' => 'password'
    ];

    $id = $db->insert('users', $data);
    if ($id) {
        echo 'user was created. Id=' . $id;
        echo $gender;
    } else {

        var_dump($db->getLastError());
        echo $gender;

    }
```

Comment: Where you have `'name' => 'name',` - should this be `'name' => $name,` so that you use the variable value rather than just the literal `name`? (same for the other fields)

Comment: Ohh thanks. There is no problem right now. :)

Comment: Use `prepare` and `bind_param` as that reduces the risk of a "Bobby Tables" `Robert'); DROP TABLE students;--` SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example (all done in a program called `so.php`)

```
<html><head><title>Insert gender</title></head></body>
<form action="so.php" method="post">
Name:<input type="text" name="name"/><br/>
Surname:<input type="text" name="surname" /><br/>
Email:<input type="text" name="email" /><br/>
Username:<input type="text" name="username" /><br/>
Password:<input type="password" name="password" /><br/>
Confirm password:<input type="password" name="password2" /><br/>
<div class="input-group form-group">
                    <label class="radio">Male
                      <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="gender" value="male" />
                      <span class="radiocheckmark"></span>
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio">Female
                      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />
                      <span class="radiocheckmark"></span>
                    </label>
                </div>
<button name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">submit</button>
</form>
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $con = new mysqli('localhost', 'mysqluser','mysqlpassword');
  if ($con->connect_error) {
    die('001T DB Connection Error: ' . $con->connect_error);   
  }

  $dbsel = $con->select_db('stackoverflow');
  if (!$dbsel) {
    die('002T Can\'t use database stackoverflow: ' . $con->error); 
  }

  $name       =$_POST["name"];
  $surname    =$_POST["surname"];
  $email      =$_POST["email"];
  $username   =$_POST["username"];
  $password   =$_POST["password"];
  $password2  =$_POST["password2"];
  $gender     =$_POST["gender"];

/* Do stuff here to sanitise input,
   compare password==password2,
   encrypt password
   etc. */

  $entry = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO register (name, surname, email,username, password, gender) VALUES( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

  $entry->bind_param('ssssss', $name, $surname, $email, $username, $password, $gender);
  $entry->execute();
  printf("Error: %s.\n",$entry->error);
  print "Entry $name added";
}
```

I created my test table as

```
CREATE TABLE `register` (
 `name` varchar(20),
 `surname` varchar(20),
 `email` varchar(20),
 `username` varchar(20),
 `password` varchar(20),
 `gender` enum('male','female')
)
```

Comment: It looks like you are storing passwords in clear text. You should not do so and instead use password_hash

Comment: Did you clearly say that anywhere? From your *example* it looks like you are suggesting to insert passwords into DB in plain text. There is a way you could make the example shorter if you removed the error displaying and used mysqli exceptions.